# How to read a file which build action is marked as embedded/resource?

Tags: c#

I have C# project, I added several html files to the solution and marked their action as "resource" or "embedded resource" ("or" -- because I don't see difference when testing).

Now I would like to read them.

When I run this code:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

I get 3 resource names in result:

```
MyApp.g.resources
MyApp.Properties.Resources.resources
MyApp.Resource.resources
```

I accessed first, I found desired file name, and I read it this way:

```
    private static byte[] getResource(string name)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
        {
            using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
            {
                string res_type;
                byte[] data;
                reader.GetResourceData(name,out res_type,out data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
```

As the result I get almost what I wanted -- the content of the file, however with some garbage bytes at the start.

How to do this correctly?

Update: the garbage sequence is -- 6, 0, 0, 239, 187, 191. Three last bytes make BOM.

Comment: What are those garbage bytes? A BOM perhaps? Just use a StreamReader over a MemoryStream initialized with your byte array to read the text.

Comment: @CodeCaster, indeed 3 bytes make BOM. However there is more (see the update). And when I convert those data to string `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data)` the result does not look nice ;-).

Comment: Because the default encoding isn't Unicode. Try the StreamReader.

Comment: @CodeCaster, with MemoryStream? Thank you, but it still give me the garbage at the beginning.

Comment: Well garbage in, garbage out. Are the source files equal to what your resource reader returns?

Comment: @CodeCaster, no, even for empty files I get those 6 bytes. And that is why I asked how to do it correctly, because input is for sure OK.

Comment: Maybe it's not a regular resource, but a BAML resource? Can you try and view it with a tool like ILSpy?

Comment: @fejesjoco, no, it is just a file, normally visible in Solution Explorer, just like regular .cs file (here .html file), the build action is set to "Resource". That's it.